# What's the perferred event to handle the end of user interaction with a UIControl?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, events

I have a view with multiple dynamically created UITextfields and UISegmented controls on it (but for purposes of this question, there could also be UIButtons, UISwitches, UISliders, or anything else that inherits from UIControl).  I want to preform an action whenever the user finished interacting with any of the controls, regardless of what subclass of control it belongs to.  From looking at other questions, I think I want to use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to add observers to each of my controls after they are created, but I don't know which event I'm looking for. I've tried all the ones that are listed [in the Apple Docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that seemed relevant but none of them seem to be triggered everytime.  I'm looking for something like `.LostFocus` in VBA, but I can't seem to find out what that is - I know there is a `becomeFirstResponder` method to make a control active, but I can't find anything like a "lostFirstResponder" event.

I suppose I could use `isKindOfClass` to tell what kind of control it is, and set up my event accordingly, but that seems a little sloppy and I feel like there should be a more direct way to do it.  I could also probably set up a UITapGestureRecognizer and build up something that way, but that still feels like a workaround and not really the way it's supposed to be done.

Comment: For example, a user could be interacting with control "A".  If the user now begins interacting with a second control "B", I'll define that as when A "looses focus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to subclass, you can override `-resignFirstResponder` to detect lost "focus", and act accordingly. This is probably only useful for things like textfields which can hold first responder status, and would not work for `UISwitch` for instance.

Since all UIControl objects are just UIViews, you can also override `touchesEnded` to detect the end of interaction with these elements.. although the more accepted way is to add your dismissal handler method as an action for all the `UIControlEvents` that indicate end of interaction, or just `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

More info on UIResponder here from Apple's Documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/resignFirstResponder

Many UIKit classes have delegate methods that indicate when interactions have ended, for instance `UITextField` has a `textFieldDidEndEditing` method. `UITextView` has similar methods.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this.  One question off the top of my head tho, how will `touchesEnded` work on a UITextField? If the user is interacting with the keypad, does that count as still being touches inside the textfield?

Comment: The UIKeyboard is an independent object with its own view. Can you be more specific about how you're defining the end of interactions for something like a UITextField? Is it when the keyboard disappears?

Comment: Hm, not necessarily, because I know the keyboard doesn't disappear when the user goes from one textfield to another textfield.  I guess I would define it as whenever the user would be finished changing data in that specific textfield.  Something like starting to interact with another control would be a trigger - actually I think that might be a workable definition as long as NavBar buttons also trigger it.  I added a comment to my question to specify this.

Comment: ok so there are several events here you can watch, `UITextFieldDelegate` has a `textFieldDidEndEditing`. In the case you described, `resignFirstResponder` would also be called when you switch text fields (or dismiss the keyboard altogether)

Comment: Right, that works for the textfields, but doesn't affect any other controls, correct?  As I mentioned in the second paragraph of my question, I know I could call `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` inside an if block to check which subclass of UIControl each control is, and pick an appropriate event to handle, but that seems like it would requires a lot of hardcoding, and would go against OOP best practice.

Comment: Ah, so the controls present in the view are dynamic. If that's the case there's no way around this, I suppose whatever factory you are using to generate the controls could add the target/action pairs on creation. You have to have type-specific logic _somewhere_ in your code, because there's no value property name commonality between different UIControl classes (for instance, `UISwitch` has an `isOn`, while `UISlider` has has a `value` property. On OSX you could bind things like takeFloatValueFrom:, but unfortunately that's not available on iOS

Comment: Yeah, the controls are dynamic, I'll edit my question to specify that.  I can't believe there is no way around it, it seems like a pretty typical thing to want to check, and I was hoping that since everything inherits from UIControl, UIControl should have some trigger to just specify that it's value has changed that applies to all of it's subclasses the same way, but I guess not.  Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: such an event does exist though, its called `UIControlEventValueChanged` but obviously doesn't apply to text input objects. You would still have to check the class type to figure out what the name of the value property is that you want to check

Comment: Yeah I saw `UIControlEventValueChanged`, and that was what I was using at first, until I realized it wasn't working for text input.  I suppose there is no `.value` property for a UITextField, but I feel like it would be pretty intuitive to figure that the event would fire when the `.text` property is changed in that case.  Guess not tho.  Alright, checking classes it is then.  Thanks again.